# Why does a local inertia frame Lorentz transform when going from $x$ to $x + dx$?

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

In Zee's GR book, pg. 600, it was written that

> On a curved manifold, as we move from point $x$ to a nearby point $x + dx$, we expect that the local frame will rotate or Lorentz transform, depending on whether the manifold is locally Euclidean or Minkowskian.

How do we know that the local inertial frame will rotate or Lorentz transform when we go from $x$ to $x+dx$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because a manifold doesn't have vectors in and of itself. You have to supplement an abstraction called the tangent space. That *is* a vector space.
Curves arise as the most natural objects to define on a manifold. And when you move from point $x$ to $x+dx$ along a curve, and if you're using the tangent space all along this displacement to find your bearings on the landscape, you must define a way to say when vectors are moving parallelly or not.
You can picture this like trying to move an arrow that describes your motion when going from a point to another on the surface of an apple. The arrow will have to rotate, to adapt to the new "tangent space". In case your manifold is locally Minkowskian, it will have to Lorentz-rotate.
Tony Zee is notorious for a pedagogical style in which he sacrifices some level of mathematical rigour in order to provide an intuitive picture, and he's a master at this. The really rigorous concept that takes you from vectors at $x$ and those at $x+dx$ is the connection.

Comment: So basically when going from $x$ to $x+dx$, we cannot use the same basis vectors at $x$, so we find another set of basis vectors by Lorentz transforming the basis vectors at $x$. The new set of basis vectors also describe a local inertial frame at $x+dx$.

Comment: You can say it that way. One of the keys to what manifolds are is that you always have a locally flat reference. The *vielbein* --around p. 600 of Zee-- $e_{\mu}\left(x\right)$ does precisely that job. In the case of a so-called "trivial bundle", like the one Zee is describing, you can always picture how the vectors change while you shift on the manifold as an infinitesimal Lorentz transformation. In more complicated cases --non-trivial-fiber bundles--, you need a more sophisticated structure to paste linear spaces to manifolds. I hope that clarified something.